# Unable to reach all hosts behind OpenVPN running on Netgear R7000

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I have OpenVPN running on an Netgear R7000 via FreshTomato firmware. I am able to connect remotely to the VPN just fine. However, I cannot ping all the hosts behind the VPN. For instance, the remote LAN Subnet is 10.0.1.X. I can ping/connect to 10.0.1.1 (the Router), 10.0.1.205 (a Windows System) but I cannot ping/connect to 10.0.1.201. I have the following in my config which I thought should allow access to all hosts:

push "route 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0"

I tested disabling the Firewall on 10.0.1.201, no joy there.

Any suggestions are welcome and appeciated.

Comment: If you can ping one device on the `10.0.1.x` LAN and not another one, that would indicate it has nothing to do with the VPN but with that `10.0.1.201` endpoint. Can it be pinged locally?

Comment: You can also try to use the router itself (either SSH to it or in the GUI under Tolls>Ping to try to ping "locally" to the `10.0.1.201` device

Comment: Please login as Rpuffd, yhen you can edit the question. Which is where changes belong. It is not obvious that you have logged in as a different user. While I have voted to  accept the changes  others may not.